# Flask to Jinja2 re-render upon executing POST request

Tags: ajax, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to re-render and display values from my Flask.

The idea is using AJAX to send a post request of my file to Flask, and retrieving values from the database, using `return render_template` to display the '<div>`

```
        if (request.method == "POST"):
            jsdata = request.form['javascript_data']

            z= db.execute("SELECT * FROM files WHERE fileName=?", (jsdata,))
            z= z.fetchall()

            return render_template('index.html', z= z, a=a, b=b, c=c)

        *other queries for initial render*
         return render_template('index.html', a=a, b=b, c=c)
```

All my other variables are able to display on load except when the POST request comes in. Any idea to go around this issue?

JS file

```
  function display(filenumber) {
      var name = document.getElementById(filenumber);
      $.post( "/", {
        javascript_data: filenumber
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hey @zzzzzzzz did you find an answer?